# Postgres: upgrade a user to be a superuser?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, alter, superuser

In postgres, how do I change an existing user to be a superuser? I don't want to delete the existing user, for various reasons.

```
# alter user myuser ...?
```

Answer (score 1422, accepted):

```
ALTER USER myuser WITH SUPERUSER;
```

You can read more at the [Documentation for ALTER USER](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alteruser.html)

Comment: the opposite operation is  `ALTER USER myuser WITH NOSUPERUSER`

Comment: and how can i detect if myuser is currently superuser?

Comment: `SELECT rolname, rolsuper FROM pg_roles;` to @masterweily

Comment: This has solved the crontab / pg_dump hell I was running into. Brilliant!

Comment: @flossfan +1 your comment, whoever downvoted this question just wants to piss people like you and me off who just want a DAMN ANSWER!

Comment: I get: ERROR:  must be superuser to alter superusers

Comment: @masterweily You can do `\du` to list all users/roles.

Comment: @stiv you can't make yourself a superuser

Comment: In case the username is a reserved word, you have to put the username inside comas, example `ALTER USER "user" WITH SUPERUSER;`

Comment: In case you're using psql and nothing seems to work, try typing out the commands all in lower case. It thought I was going insane but it looks like my psql client doesn't like UPPER CASE syntax.

Comment: @StepanYakovenko use  `sudo su - postgres` and then `psql` before you try this command.

Answer (score 75):

To expand on the above and make a quick reference:

- To make a user a SuperUser: `ALTER USER username WITH SUPERUSER;`
- To make a user no longer a SuperUser: `ALTER USER username WITH NOSUPERUSER;`
- To just allow the user to create a database: `ALTER USER username CREATEDB;`

You can also use `CREATEROLE` and `CREATEUSER` to allow a user privileges without making them a superuser.

[Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alteruser.html)

Comment: `CREATE ROLE dba WITH SUPERUSER;`
`GRANT dba TO username;`
User `username` can than become superuser only **on demand** using `SET ROLE dba;`.
In log file are commands still logged under `username`.

Answer (score 38):

$ `su - postgres`
$ `psql` 
$ `\du;` for see the user on db 
select the user that do you want be superuser and:
$  `ALTER USER "user" with superuser;`

Comment: in this specific case, you have to put the username inside comas, example `ALTER USER "user" WITH SUPERUSER;`

Comment: @Carlos.V Because `user` is a reserved word, yes.

Answer (score 13):

May be sometimes upgrading to a superuser might not be a good option.
So apart from super user there are lot of other options which you can use.
Open your terminal and type the following:

```
$ sudo su - postgres
[sudo] password for user: (type your password here)
$ psql
postgres@user:~$ psql
psql (10.5 (Ubuntu 10.5-1.pgdg18.04+1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# ALTER USER my_user WITH option
```

Also listing the list of options

```
SUPERUSER | NOSUPERUSER | CREATEDB | NOCREATEDB  | CREATEROLE | NOCREATEROLE |
CREATEUSER | NOCREATEUSER | INHERIT | NOINHERIT | LOGIN | NOLOGIN | REPLICATION|
NOREPLICATION | BYPASSRLS | NOBYPASSRLS | CONNECTION LIMIT connlimit | 
[ ENCRYPTED | UNENCRYPTED ] PASSWORD 'password' | VALID UNTIL 'timestamp'
```

So in command line it will look like

```
postgres=# ALTER USER my_user WITH  LOGIN
```

OR use an encrypted password.

```
postgres=# ALTER USER my_user  WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD '5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592';
```

OR revoke permissions after a specific time.

```
postgres=# ALTER USER my_user  WITH VALID UNTIL '2019-12-29 19:09:00';
```

Answer (score 10):

Run this Command

```
alter user myuser with superuser;
```

If you want to see the permission to a user run following command

```
\du
```

Answer (score 6):

You can create a `SUPERUSER` or promote `USER`, so for your case

```
$ sudo -u postgres psql -c "ALTER USER myuser WITH SUPERUSER;"
```

or rollback

```
$ sudo -u postgres psql -c "ALTER USER myuser WITH NOSUPERUSER;"
```

*To prevent a command from logging when you set password, insert a whitespace in front of it, but check that your system supports this option.*

```
$  sudo -u postgres psql -c "CREATE USER my_user WITH PASSWORD 'my_pass';"
$  sudo -u postgres psql -c "CREATE USER my_user WITH SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'my_pass';"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
alter user username superuser;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you reached this because you're using Amazon Redshift you CANNOT assign `SUPERUSER`

```
ALTER USER <username> SUPERUSER;
```

Instead assign `CREATEUSER`:

```
ALTER USER <username> CREATEUSER;
```

Apparently, `SUPERUSER` isn't an available user assignment in Amazon Redshift clusters. I am utterly confused by this.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_superusers.html

Screenshots showing this:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyWXt.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycbeL.png

Answer (score 1):

Login to postgres database with the postgres user.

\c postgres postgres

Issue \du command to check current roles granted to user.

Issue the command to grant superuser:
alter user username with superuser;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

It is quite easy to switch between making user a superuser or a regular user.
First do check the permissions of all the users by using following command.

```
\du
```

Then make user superuser by using following command

```
ALTER USER user_name WITH SUPERUSER;
```

and reverse by using following command

```
ALTER USER user_name WITH NOSUPERUSER;
```

for further understanding, explore the following tutorial:
[How to Change a User to Superuser in PostgreSQL](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-change-a-user-to-superuser-in-postgresql/)

Answer (score 0):

Found a better command to alter the status of a user.

```
ALTER USER myuser WITH SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'pgpassword' VALID UNTIL '2034-12-2';
```

Ig there are niche cases for the valid until. You could use that for password rotation and temporary access.

Answer (score -1):

For example, you can make the user(role) `john` a superuser (by a superuser) as shown below according to [ALTER ROLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterrole.html) and [ALTER USER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alteruser.htm). *You must log in with any superusers(e.g., `postgres`) and you can omit `WITH` which is optional:

```sql
ALTER ROLE john WITH SUPERUSER;
```

Or:

```sql
ALTER USER john WITH SUPERUSER;
```

In addition, you can make the user(role) `john` a non-superuser as shown below:

```sql
ALTER ROLE john WITH NOSUPERUSER;
```

Or:

```sql
ALTER USER john WITH NOSUPERUSER;
```