# How to grant all privileges to all databases in postgres

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a user test. I want to grant all privileges to this user on all databases.
How can it be done?

Comment: That doesn't sound like a smart idea.

Answer (score 1):

Run this command from psql:

```
ALTER USER myuser WITH SUPERUSER;
```

from [postgres: upgrade a user to be a superuser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757431/postgres-upgrade-a-user-to-be-a-superuser)

Comment: Its a aws rds postgres server. I am not able to create a superuser

Answer (score 1):

For aws use: GRANT rds_superuser TO youruser;

Comment: This will give access to all tables, databases and schemas?

Comment: I don't see anything under attributes section for this user

Comment: Now, I don't have a  pg on aws to confirm, but is in the official docs: " The rds_superuser role is a predefined Amazon RDS role similar to the PostgreSQL superuser role (customarily named postgres in local instances), but with some restrictions. As with the PostgreSQL superuser role, the rds_superuser role has the most privileges for your DB instance. You should not assign this role to users unless they need the most access to the DB instance. "

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.html